# Pushing both keys and value into an json array structure dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have angularjs front end code as follows:

```js
function addController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tableNames = [];
  $scope.addNewColumn = function(item) {
    $scope.tableNames.push({})
  }
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="addController">
  <div class="col-sm-10">

    <fieldset ng-repeat="item in tableNames track by $index">
      <span> TextBox1:<input type="text" ng-model="item.item1" />
          TextBox2:<input type="text" ng-model="item.item2" /></span>

    </fieldset>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNewColumn()">Add Colname</button>
  </div>
  <pre>{{tableNames|json}}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I enter text in the textbox1 and textbox2 it shows array of below format:

```
[{
"item1":"textbox1value",
"item2":"textbox2value"
}]
```

and also when i click addColname button and generate another textbox, values are pushed in different property as follows,it generates:

```
[{
"item1":"textbox1value",
"item2":"textbox2value"
},
{
"item1":"textbox1value",
"item2":"textbox2value"
}
]
```

but what actually i need is of structure,

```
[{
"textbox1value":"textbox2value",
"textbox1value":"textbox2value",
.....
}]
```

note(:`"textboxvalue"` are values entered inside textboxes.

somebody help me to get desired output. thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to display a table of values from tableNames and then add new items to that table?

Comment: yes. but i need tableNames array structure as i have asked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working code. I hope this helps :)

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>
    function addController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.tableNames = []; 
        $scope.getData={};
        var i=-1;

        $scope.addNewColumn = function (item) {
            $scope.tableNames.push({})
            i++;
        }
        $scope.addData = function(item){
            if(i >= 0){ 
                $scope.newData=[];
      $scope.getData[$scope.tableNames[i].item1]=$scope.tableNames[i].item2;
                $scope.newData.push($scope.getData);
        }
    }


}  

</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="addController">      
<div class="col-sm-10">

    <fieldset ng-repeat="item in tableNames track by $index">
        <span> TextBox1:<input type="text" ng-model="item.item1" ng-keyup="addData()"/>
      TextBox2:<input type="text" ng-model="item.item2" ng-keyup="addData()"/></span>

    </fieldset>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNewColumn()">Add Colname</button>

</div>
    <pre>{{newData|json}}</pre>


</body>
</html>
```